# Sublime: How can I jump n lines with the keyboard arrows?

Tags: text, editor, sublimetext3, text-editor

I feel very tedious when I have to percor the text file with the arrow, line by line, but I feel that PageDown/PageUp makes me lose where I was.

Is there a way that I can simply jump n lines using a simply shortcut (like ctrl+arrow down/up)? I think that 5 lines would fits me very well.

Comment: just solved this. I was randomly combining hotkeys them found that ctrl+alt+arrowLeft/Right solves this problem.

Comment: Wrong... didn't solve. That wasn't what I was planning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built in movement commands allow you to move in a variety of ways, but only one move at a time (e.g. one line up, one word left, one page down, etc).

As Ben mentions in his answer, one way around that is to create macros that make the movements that you want, bind keys to run the macros, and you're good to go.

Another alternative is to use a simple plugin such as the following (originally from [this forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/command-to-move-by-several-lines/28508/3?u=odatnurd)), which you can use by selecting `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu, replacing the stub code with this code, and then saving in the default location as something like `move_amount.py`:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MoveAmountCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, amount=1, **kwargs):
        for _ in range(amount):
            self.view.run_command("move", args=kwargs)
```

This creates a command named `move_amount` that wraps the internal `move` command, providing an extra argument of `amount` to indicate how many times to take the move action. This can be handy if you have a few such bindings to make as it cuts down on the number of macros that you have to make and it's easier to customize them.

With that in place you can use the following key bindings, modifying the amount as desired:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+up"], "command": "move_amount",
    "args": {"by": "lines", "amount": 5, "forward": false}
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+down"], "command": "move_amount",
    "args": {"by": "lines", "amount": 5, "forward": true}
},
```

Note that these keys are already bound to the `scroll_lines` command, which scrolls the viewport but leaves the caret alone, so if you use that functionality as well you may want to select different bindings.

Comment: Nice, way cleaner. Used this today on a fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell there isn't an actual keyboard shortcut that will let you combine a move lines command with an amount to move.

Instead you can record & save two different macros. One moving up 5 lines, the other moving down 5 lines - (start recording macro, then hit the up or down arrow x number of times. stop recording, then save.).

Then you can create a binding to call them from your preferences file:

```
[
    { "keys": ["shift+alt+up"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/up-five-lines.sublime-macro"} },
    { "keys": ["shift+alt+down"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/down-five-lines.sublime-macro"} }

]
```